# Parsing files to populate placeholders with values

Tags: build, gruntjs, readme

#### Background Info

I have a JS library which consists of many constructor functions. I am using `grunt-concat` & `-uglify` to compile these into a single file.

Each constructor has a `readme.md` file.

The library is used to create advertising banners. It is used by around 10 developers who create their own advertising templates within a folder `Templates` which use the library. The files are `.xml` files which also provide a `CDATA` tag where they can insert their JavaScript code.

#### Question

I would like to populate the `readme` files with a counter, so that the developers can see how popular a particular constructor is directly in its documentation.

> Number of occurrences (<% occurrences %>)

#### What I've already done

I can get the number of occurrences by executing

`find . -name "*.xml" -exec grep -e "new\Foo\.Bar" {} \; | wc -l`

It would be great if I could grab this value and insert it to the `readme` file.

Answer (score 0):

```
grunt.registerTask('count_occurrences', '', function () {
        var exec = require('child_process').execSync;
        var result = exec("find . -name "*.xml" -exec grep -e "new\Foo\.Bar" {} \; | wc -l", { encoding: 'utf8' });

        grunt.log.writeln(result);
        // Now write result to your README file
        grunt.file.write("README.md", result);
});
```

or

You can use the grunt plugin called `exec` (https://github.com/jharding/grunt-exec) to execute cmd line functions, e.g. `find`.

You probably would want something like this in your `GruntFile.js`:

```
exec: {
  count_occurrences: {
    cmd: function() {
      return 'find . -name "*.xml" -exec grep -e "new\Foo\.Bar" {} \; | wc -l';
    }
  }
}
```

Then call `grunt exec:echo_name`